# Using Form Submissions to Build URLs without using values as URL paramters

Tags: html, forms, freemarker

Consider a simple `HTML` form with one input. And this form sends the parameters to a `freemarker` function.

```html
  
<form action="${getURL('')}" method="GET">
  
   <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="AR">
  
   <input type="submit" class="form_submit" value="View">

</form>
```

Freemarker function

```
<#function lang="" page="0">
  <#if lang?? >
      <#return '${context}/${lang?lower_case}?page=${page}'/>
  <#else>
      <#return '#' />
  </#if>
</#function>
```

The problem I have is when use submit, the generated URL will always be like

```
www.example.com/?page=0&lang=ar
```

I have a different version of the freemarker function to generate a valid URL like

```
www.example.com?page=0&lang=ar
```

**But what I want is to reduce URL parameters and go for sub-domain type URL structure with minimum number of URL parameters.** Is it possible to generate a URL like

```
www.example.com/ar?page=0
```

using above mentioned form? Or `form` submissions with GET always create URLs with URL parameters?

Please ignore the syntax errors in the code I just wanted to clarify my problem using the code snippet. And I do not want to use any scripting to get this done (`javascript`, `jquery`). Any clarification is highly appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with Freemarker, but it's a templating language, right? If it outputs HTML, there's no way to get a form field's value to become part of the submission URL's path, client-side without script. If it's a known value like your example, why aren't you adding it to the action attribute?

Comment: Yes freemarker is a template library. the value is not a known value. I just put it there to say there is a input inside the form. And in the real scenario, the "lang" value is dynamic. 
@Walf  Yes it is kind of misleading. Thank you for pointing it out. 
But as you said it seems impossible to do it. But I want to make sure it is impossible.

Comment: If it's only some kind of search, you're wasting time. If you're also linking to these pages in other ways, and your site accepts SEF URLs to them, then add `rel=canonical` links to the pages' heads, or redirect to the prettier URL upon submission.

Comment: I solved it using converting **GET** to **POST**. In that way No URL parameters are created. And in the server level I am redirecting the user to the new URL. Thank you for your answer. +1 for mentioning canonical tag.